How to change the poster's name when creating a post to a channel via MS Teams Workflows
Since the Office 365 connectors are going away I changed my project to use MS Teams Workflows, Im using the "Post to a channel when a webhook request is received" template to send some notifications to Teams from my app.
So far is working fine but Im having a small issue.
When the post is sent It appears as sent by me

And I would prefer it to be a generic name like "General" or "System Monitor".
I've been looking at the documentation but I don't find anything useful to change the author's name.

I'm having the same issue, could you fix it somehow?

This would be a nice feature. Prasad-MSFT's answer isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

I have the same problem where you able to resolve this?

If you want to send by using option 'Flow bot', it will send as below


If you want the sender's name only to be reflected without via Workflows text, you can choose below option while setting up/editing the workflow.
User's image
This will send the card as below:


